# Is Delicious feeds API no longer supported?

Tags: delicious

I've used Delicious feeds, such as http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/username/optional_tag for a few years, but it seems like recently (end of 2015) they stopped working.

Did Delicious drop support for their feeds, or is this a temporary glitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Server:
https://previous.delicious.com/v2/rss/....
but no news on delicious.com

Found it on:
http://www.dizzysoft.com/how-to-get-rss-feeds-from-the-new-delicious/

but since August, 2015 it did not show new links.

Comment: Thank you, replaced "feeds" with "previous", and it worked. interestingly it seems like Inoreader (one of the places I was using those feeds) also automatically updated my feeds in the last day without me doing anything.

Comment: Does not seem to work for me: `previous.delicious.com` domain is not found. I asked the NS at, `delicious.com` but it says it does not know it.